# Is there a faster way to create conditional email handlers with Drupal 8 than adding emails one by one?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-webform

I'm creating a Drupal 8 webform that will collect issues submitted by users. The users belong to different institutions, and I'd like to send the submission to the appropriate institutional contact (selected from a drop-down list in the form).

I've used conditional logic to create a handler "if [institution1] selected, email to institution1@gmail.com" and while it works well, I have a lot of institutions (and several different forms to create). Does anyone know if there is a faster way to conditionally assign a contact email for each institution, and to repeat/save this across multiple forms?

Added handler, set conditional logic to select if value "Institutional1" is filled. Duplicated handlers, changing the email and filled value each time.

Comment: I have not used webform for a while... But I would.. Have a content type of "institution" in the site with a field to hold the email address.. In the webform have a select element and then use a form alter to populate the select element with the instititions email and label(email as the value), then in your webform, you should be able to tell it to send the email to the selected value of the select element. Just my first thought on how I would do it. Saying that, there might already be a way to populate a webform select element with entity references.

Comment: The main point is, you should probably create a content type for saving the institutions (and its email address), then try to populate the form with the values rather than inputting them all multiple times.

Comment: Thank you @2pha that helps! I've created a predefined list for the Select element, with Option Value [Institutional email] and Option Text [Institution name]. The only challenge I am finding now is that when I edit the email handler, I can see the Institution names, but the email addresses are blank. I've added them in, and it's definitely faster than creating conditional handlers for each institution, but I am wondering why I don't see the email I already specified for that value.